# NDEF - split log into several NDEF messages?

Tags: nfc, ndef

I'm new to NFC, and I'm working on a project where I will need to transfer an error log from a gas meter to a mobile phone via NFC. Since NFC is working with NDEF messages, i came across a problem.

For the moment I'm in the research phase, and I can see that the amount of data per transfer for NFC is quite low. I do not yet know the exact size of the log, but what can I do if the log is too big for one NDEF message? And no, i do not mean NDEF Records, i mean NDEf message. I get that an NDEF message is composed of NDEF records, but in the case of the log being too large for one NDEF meesage, would it be possible to split the log into two or more NDEF messages and still be able to get the information needed from the log file on the receiving device?

Comment: How do you plan to store the log data into the NFC chip? Will you use a NFC chip with I2C interface, which a microcontroller can use to write the data to? Or do you other ideas in mind?

Comment: I had something along those lines in mind yes. So that the microcontroller will forward the data to the chip using I2C or perhaps SPI. I'm not dead settled on this yet, I'm researching and trying to figure out how to achieve what I want to achieve and what chip etc. to use. But yes, that is the idea, at least for now.

Comment: What size of log do you need to transfer?

Answer (score 0):

Discard use of the NDEF format if your data does not fit, or re-purpose the NDEF payload to rather *point* to the desired data - for example a link to the log content etc..

That being said, I doubt that you really *need* such a long error log. Rather than a textual format, compile the log statements into a binary form.